# moveit_setup_assistant cannot load pr2.urdf.xacro

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the **moveit official tutorial** to **roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant**, and then **load the pr2.urdf.xacro file**, and come across error then the **assistant crashes**.

Here is the tutorial link: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

**Note:**

1, indigo on Ubuntu 14

2,
Information about **OpenGL** by command line :**glxinfo | grep OpenGL**

**No error shown here.**

```
root@ShawnVM:~/catkin_ws/src/rbx2/pi_robot_moveit_config# glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

**Here is the error information with both text and image version:**

```
root@ShawnVM:/opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_setup_assistant# roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
... logging to /root/.ros/log/1740324a-a756-11e6-9533-000c290a3fdb/roslaunch-ShawnVM-81395.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ShawnVM:33182/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[moveit_setup_assistant-1]: started with pid [81413]
[rospack] Error: no package given
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ INFO] [1478834698.670836156]: Running 'rosrun xacro xacro.py /opt/ros/indigo/share/pr2_description/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro'...
[ INFO] [1478834703.591787951]: Loaded pr2 robot model.
[ INFO] [1478834703.591918734]: Setting Param Server with Robot Description
[ INFO] [1478834703.608182827]: Robot semantic model successfully loaded.
[ INFO] [1478834703.608598789]: Setting Param Server with Robot Semantic Description
[ INFO] [1478834703.620308337]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1478834703.620406108]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1478834703.777751659]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1478834703.777928749]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ INFO] [1478834703.937708930]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1478834703.937975156]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
[ INFO] [1478834704.959022007]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1478834704.959187880]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
================================================================================REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-1] has died!
process has died [pid 81413, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/root/.ros/log/1740324a-a756-11e6-9533-000c290a3fdb/moveit_setup_assistant-1.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/1740324a-a756-11e6-9533-000c290a3fdb/moveit_setup_assistant-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

[image: image description]

**Edit1:**

I follow this answer  http://answers.ros.org/question/217186/a-problem-with-launching-the-moveit-setup-assistant/

try to install xserver-xorg, but another things shown up

```
root@ShawnVM:/opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_setup_assistant# sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**Edit2:**
Then, I have to sovle **Edit1** problem, which leads me to this
http://askubuntu.com/questions/575548/system-settings-stopped-showing-up

But it does not work for me.  Still cannot **install xserver**

**Edit3:**
I forgot to mention that, **moveit_setup_assistant can load the pi_robot.urdf file in the ros-by-example-2 tutorial**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247687/moveit_setup_assistant-cannot-load-pr2.urdf.xacro/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-10**:
Please don't use screenshots for what is essentially text. Could you copy-paste the console text into your question, then use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) next time? Text in imgs is not searchable by search engines, leading to reduced visibility of this question.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-11-10**:
I don't think this will fix your problem, but note your tutorial link is for Hydro and very out of date - the latest tutorials are here: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-10**:
Thanks, I did follow this tutorial.  when I post the question, I search this tutorial it shows the old link, for saving time, I just copy the old link, sorry. Actually, they are the same, at least for the first two steps.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-10**:
sometimes the **101010** does not work well in the edit window

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-22**:
Should I check the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your dependencies are correctly installed, there is a fair chance this has something to do with your graphics driver. From the output it seems like the urdf is parsed correctly but the program crashes when it starts to make use of OpenGL. Are you by any chance running a VM?

Some more information can be found in these related topics:

[MoveIt setup assistant crashes when loading a urdf](http://answers.ros.org/question/200628/moveit-setup-assistant-crashes-when-loading-a-urdf/)

[a problem with launching the moveit setup assistant](http://answers.ros.org/question/217186/a-problem-with-launching-the-moveit-setup-assistant/)

[problems with moveit exit code-11](http://answers.ros.org/question/193137/problems-with-moveit-exit-code-11/)

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-10**:
Yes, I am running on VM

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2016-11-10**:
Did you manage to solve the problem using the posted questions?

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-10**:
Not yet, becase it seems OpenGL works well, I think. See the update on my post

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-10**:
[In this question and answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/217186/a-problem-with-launching-the-moveit-setup-assistant/)
This man solved his problem by this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

which seems confusing.
I haven't tried it yet.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-11-10**:
It is likely because of the VM, yes

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, I gave up on using ROS on Ubuntu on VMware. I install dual boot system, and directly run ROS on Ubuntu, no error occurs.

It seems large gui program does not work well on Virtual Machine due to graphics card, I suppose.

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1